# Find the square of each item in list .o/p should be a list .write program using lambda , using comprehension , using loop

Tags: python-3.x, for-loop, lambda, list-comprehension

Find the square of each item in list .o/p should be a list .write  program using lambda , using comprehension , using loop .

I have tried below but there is no for loop in the below program and i need
to have lambda ,for loop with list comprehension method..

```
x =[i**2 for i in l1]
print(x)
[1, 4, 9]


squares = map(lambda x:x*x,l1)
print(list(squares))

[1, 4, 9]

y =map(lambda x: x*x,range(1,10))
print(list(y))

[1, 4, 9, 16, 25, 36, 49, 64, 81]

def square(x): return lambda : x*x

listOfLambdas = [square(i)  for i in range(1, 6)]
for f in listOfLambdas:
   print(f)

output
<function square.<locals>.<lambda> at 0x02FF7DB0>
<function square.<locals>.<lambda> at 0x02FF7DF8>
<function square.<locals>.<lambda> at 0x02FF7E40>
<function square.<locals>.<lambda> at 0x02FF7E88>
<function square.<locals>.<lambda> at 0x02FF7ED0>
```

Comment: listOfLambdas = [lambda i=i: i*i for i in range(6)]
for f in listOfLambdas:
    print (f)   o/p <function <listcomp>.<lambda> at 0x02C7E5D0>
<function <listcomp>.<lambda> at 0x02EE7D68>
<function <listcomp>.<lambda> at 0x02EE7DB0>
<function <listcomp>.<lambda> at 0x02EE7DF8>
<function <listcomp>.<lambda> at 0x02EE7E40>
<function <listcomp>.<lambda> at 0x02EE7E88>
>>>

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As you have tried returning a lambda function from a function. 
So when ever you are calling square function by using list comprehension, it is returning the object of lambda function, on each call. So if you want to execute that lambda function from list, try the below code

```
def square(x): return lambda x: x*x

listOfLambdas = [square(i)(i)  for i in range(1, 6)]
for f in listOfLambdas:
    print(f)
```

I hope this would help.

Comment: But the output is not coming as list format...it comes as 1
4
9
16
25   ,Expection are [1,4,9,16,25,] without using any new empty list and appending it..something like  l3.append(f)

Comment: You are using list comprehension, so output would be a list. So if you check the data type of listofLambdas variable it is a list. and it contains your data as you expect it to be  [1,4,9,16,25,]

Comment: dont we have any implementation where we use lambda in the list comprehension and not calling it in another function like square(x) ?

Comment: Try this code : [(lambda x: x*x)(x) for x in range(10)]    but this not the correct way